# total length of list by summing length of each element

Tags: python

I have a small question.
I am trying to find the the amount of letters in my list.

```
list = ['Chris', 'jan']
len(list)
```

would give me then 2, because there are 2 elements in my list. 
Is their a possibility to calculate the amount of letters in my list? So the outcome would be 8 (length of the first element + length of the second element)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can just map the `len` function over the list to apply it to each element and then sum the resulting lengths' list

```
a = ['Chris', 'jan']

>>> sum(map(len, a))
8
```

Alternatively, you can also join the list of strings into a single string and get its length

```
>>> len(''.join(a))
8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sum the length of each word.

```
sum(len(w) for w in l)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
len("".join(list))
```